# Position one <Image> on center and one <Image> on right in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to place two images on the Appbar of my application built in React Native, but I can't make it work properly. The first image must be positioned in the middle of the Appbar, while the second one must be positioned in the right of it. The following image shows how it should be:

[image: Example of positioning]

Currently, I'm trying this way:

```
<View style={viewStyle}>
    <Image source={require('../images/rank.jpg')} style={styles.imageStyle} />\
    <Image source={require('../images/ic_notifications.png')} style={styles.notificationStyle} />
</View>

const styles = {
  viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#022436',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    elevation: 2,
    position: 'relative'
  },
  imageStyle: {
    height: 35,
    width: 120
  },
  notificationStyle: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  }
};
```

But both images are centered in the Appbar. Also tried to create a View in the same level of the `rank.jpg` image, but nothing changed.

**SOLUTION (provided by @Travis White):**

```
<View style={viewStyle}>
    <View style={{ flex:1 }} />
    <View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Image source={require('../images/rank.jpg')} style={styles.imageStyle} />
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
      <Image source={require('../images/ic_notifications.png')} style={styles.notificationStyle} />
    </View>
  </View>

const styles = {
  viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#022436',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    elevation: 2,
    position: 'relative'
  },
  imageStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 35,
    width: null
  },
  notificationStyle: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    margin: 12
  }
};
```

I still have a doubt about a performance issue that may arise with the inclusion of empty `<View>`s. If anyone can explain it.

Comment: If you're truly worried about performance with that extra/empty View, then you could make it work by setting `notificationStyle` to `{ position: 'absolute', right: 12, top: 12}` Multiple ways to make it work. I like to avoid absolute positioning unless necessary as you then have to worry about overlap and a few other things. Centering/tweaking becomes more difficult, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you want to divide the top into 3 equal parts. Why not use a View as placeholder to the first section. Give all three components `flex: 1`, and you should be in good shape. If the images give you an issue, you can simply make them children of a View with `flex: 1` set, so all children of the `viewStyle` view are being divided equally with flex: 1 set.

Comment: Is there any performance issue to create an empty View only to fit this type of UI? Because I don't need any element on the left part of the Bar, only in the middle and in the right.

Comment: Not enough to worry about, IMO.

Comment: I'll try this way.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
<View style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "space-between"
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ alignItems: "center", flex: 1 }}>
                <Image
                  style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
                  source={{
                    uri:
                      "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png"
                  }}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={{ alignItems: "center", marginRight: 10 }}>
                <Image
                  style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
                  source={{
                    uri:
                      "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png"
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
```

Comment: This puts the first image off center. It centers it based on remaining space after the right side image is accounted for whereas it should be centered on the whole screen. This would work if you positioned the right image absolutely and set it's position properly.

Comment: This is what I wanted. I wanted to have text on left side and image on right side. `justifyContent: "space-between"` this did the trick